# How to configure logging separately for Tomcat, an application, and a library with logback?

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, slf4j, logback

I'm trying to essentially configure logging in three places, independently.  Ideally, each component that is logging is fully unaware of the others.  I'd like to use logback for this, as it seems to have some decent features and performance.

Here are the places from which I would like to log from and to:

1. Tomcat (7) should log to ${catalina_home}/logs/catalina.out, and should only log Tomcat events (deployments, server startup, etc)
2. A web application hosted in Tomcat should log to ${catalina_home}/logs/application.log, and should only log application things, like results of request validations or errors
3. A library that is included in the web application should log to ${catalina_home}/logs/library.log, and should only log things specific to that library, like time it takes to interact with some other web-service or library-specific errors

I know this is probably not the way it would work, but I would think I need to have a logback.xml file for each concern.  Actually, I have created them and added to the classpath such that I get a "logback.xml occurs multiple times on the classpath" error.

I can see why I would need to consolidat my application and my library logback configuration to a single logback.xml file, but how would I keep the container logging config separate from the application+library logging config?  Adding a logback config file to my application, as well as logback enabling Tomcat as described [here](http://hwellmann.blogspot.com/2012/11/logging-with-slf4j-and-logback-in.html), still yields a "multiple logback.xml" error.  And, [Chapter 9](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/loggingSeparation.html) of the logback user manual, which talks about separation of logging, doesn't really show how to separate the container and applications (just multiple applications), unless I am missing something there.

Comment: Im facing right now the same Problem (1 + 2 of your points). Im getting no error but it doesnt work. Having seperated logback.xml files (+libs, configs etc) for my webapp and tomcat7 but they are logging into the same logfile. Did you find any new informations about this? I ve seen some blogs but most of them look either outdated or they show often only how to replace JULI with logback in tomcat but NOT the interaction with webapps which also use logback...

Comment: I never got this to work with logback, but succeeded in getting my application to use log4j2, and the Tomcat container to use JUL.  The trick to getting it working 100% is to make sure your transitive dependencies don't include an SLFJ logging implementation by adding "exclude" clauses to their "dependency" declarations in your POM file (if you are using Maven).  In my log4j2.xml file, I send the log events from certain dependencies to different files by filtering the package namespaces, and keep the logs separate in that manner.